# How can I unmaximize programmatically a maximized frame in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Let's say I have a simple application such as the following:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'This is the frame title')
frame.Show()
frame.Maximize()    

app.MainLoop()
```

Is there a method I can call on the frame to un-maximize it? I have tried `frame.Unmaximize()` and `frame.Maximize(False)` but the former is `undefined`, while the latter seems to 'fail' silently in Ubuntu.

[Here](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TopLevelWindow.html#Maximize) it says that `Maximize(False)` is the way to go. Is there a bug I should submit, or is there something else I miss here?

Comment: FYI Frame.Maximize(False) works on OSX and Win7 with python 2.7.x and wxpython 3.0.0

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll play with it some more today (just to make sure) and then I'll probably submit a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this program under OSX, Win7 and Ubuntu:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'This is the frame title')
frame.Show()
frame.Maximize() 
frame.Maximize(False)   

app.MainLoop()
```

On OSX and Win7 the frame visibly maximises then minimises.

On Ubuntu (wxpython 2.8.11 gtk-unicode), the Maximise commands appear completely ignored.  I can delete the Maximize(False) line and the frame still isn't maximised.

This is with xfwm4 on Ubuntu 11.10

Looks like a bug to me.   But it may also be a window manager quirk.

---

Amusingly, google finds a bug report where Frame.Maximize() works only on windows.   But it is 11 years old.   Maybe Linux has not been added yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `Restore()`. While under MSW and OS X it's exactly the same as `Maximize(false)`, in wxGTK it's implemented slightly differently, so perhaps it works even under Ubuntu.

Comment: Then it's another Ubuntu breakage of standard GTK+ API :-( Unfortunately there is not much we can do about it, if an OS intentionally prevents the API we use from working, the only thing we (and our users) can do is to complain to them about it -- but this is perfectly useless in Ubuntu case...